# Haskell simple show the elements of a list program

Tags: haskell

I try to make a function in Haskell to show the elements of a list and it doesn't work. What do I do wrong?

```
showw :: [Int a]=> [a] -> b
showw []=0
showw (x:xs)= x ++ showw xs
```

It gives me this error :

```
aplicatie.hs:1:12: error: 
• Expected a constraint, but ‘[Int a]’ has kind ‘*’ 
• In the type signature: afisare :: [Int a] => [a] -> b
aplicatie.hs:1:13: error: 
• Expecting one fewer argument to ‘Int’ Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but 
  ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’ 
• In the type signature: afisare :: [Int a] => [a] -> b
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: It gives me this error : 
aplicatie.hs:1:12: error:
    • Expected a constraint, but ‘[Int a]’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature:
        afisare :: [Int a] => [a] -> b

aplicatie.hs:1:13: error:
    • Expecting one fewer argument to ‘Int’
      Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature:
        afisare :: [Int a] => [a] -> b

Comment: You should add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

The first problem is in the type signature. Int is a type, but your syntax makes it look like a type class. If you have a function which takes a list of Ints and outputs some other value, it should look like this:

```
func :: [Int] -> a
```

Of course, that only works if you mean to restrict the function to Ints. If you want to include other kinds of numbers, you *do* need to use a type class. If you wanted to use Num, for instance, the type signature would instead look like this:

```
func :: Num a => a -> b
```

But even if you fix your type signature you're still going to get an error, because the return type of your function isn't consistent. `showw []` returns 0 (an Int), but `showw` on a non-empty list returns a list of values. You probably want `showw []` to return `[0]` or `[]` instead.

And if you want to *show* these values, as in convert them to a string, you'll need to use a function to do that conversion. You would apply that function to `x` on the third line, and to the return value of `showw []`.

Comment: Nice first sentence, bro

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here.  First, constraints are written using parentheses, not brackets:

```
showw :: (Int a) => [a] -> b
```

That gets rid of one error.

Now I'm not sure what you're intending `(Int a)`, but `Int` isn't a typeclass so you can't use it like this.  Maybe you meant `a` is an `Int`, in which case we would not use a type variable at all and just use the `Int` type in its place:

```
showw :: [Int] -> b
```

Now there's this `b` floating around all by its lonesome, and lonely type variables are generally a problem.  It says that `showw` can return *any type at all*, so if I said, hey, `showw`, here's `[1,2,3,4,5]`, give me back an `Elephant` it would have to return an elephant.

Since you want to "show" the list, I assume you want to return a `String`

```
showw :: [Int] -> String
```

Which is a reasonable signature.   Now to the implementation:

```
show [] = 0
```

To show an empty list, you... give 0?  That doesn't make sense.  You probably want the empty string `""`.

And then this line:

```
showw (x:xs) = x ++ showw xs
```

in which you try to concatenate an `Int` (`x`) with a `String` (`showw xs`), which is not allowed.  You need to convert `x` to a string first, and I guess you should do that using the regular `show` function.

That said, the `show` function can already show lists.  But I assume you're practicing.

Comment: How should the final program look?Sorry but i am new in Haskell